# Using singular value decomposition to assess approximate non-trivial solutions to A x = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Given an $N \times 4$ matrix $A$ $(N \geq 4),$ I can find an approximate (non-trivial) solution to the homogeneous equation $A x = 0$ using [*singular value decomposition (SVD)*](http://newton.uam.mx/xgeorge/uea/graficacionII/homogeneous_equations.pdf) assuming that one of the singular values is sufficiently small. Say the SVD yields $A = U \Sigma V^T$ and the smallest singular value is $\sigma,$ then the corresponding column of $V$ yields the approximate solution $\hat{x}.$ Can I quantify how good this solution is based on $\sigma$? Perhaps $\sigma$ tells me something about the magnitude of $\| A \hat{x} \|$?

For example, the matrix

$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   2 & 2 & 2 & 2.3 \\
   4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
   -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   5 & 5.1 & 5 &5 \\
   3.1 & 3 & 3 &3
\end{array}
\right]
$$
[has singular values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=svd%20of%20%7B%7B2%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202.3%7D%2C%20%7B4%2C4%2C4%2C4%7D%2C%20%7B-1%2C-1%2C-1%2C-1%7D%2C%20%7B5%2C5.1%2C5%2C5%7D%2C%20%7B3.1%2C%203%2C3%2C3%7D%7D)
$\sigma_1 = 14.9275,$ $\sigma_2 = 0.260285,$
$\sigma_3 = 0.0986021,$ $\sigma_4 = 0.0322844.$ The last column of
$V$ is $\hat{x} = [-0.313176,\ -0.457528,\ 0.830508,\ -0.0533385]^T$ which corresponds
to $\sigma_4.$ We see this solution is close:
$$
A \hat{x} = \left[\begin{array}{c}
  -0.00307055 \\
0.025862 \\
-0.0064655 \\
-0.0134253 \\
-0.0119211
\end{array}\right] \approx \mathbf{0}
$$
([check here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=magnitude%20of%20%7B-0.00307055%2C%200.025862%2C%20-0.0064655%2C%20-0.0134253%2C%20-0.0119211%7D)) and $\| A \hat{x} \| = 0.0322866.$
We know the solution is normalized ($\| \hat{x} \|^2 = 1$), but can we quantify
the error in the solution based on $\sigma_4?$

***Edit:*** fixed arithmetic errors which match the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, $\| A \hat x \| = \sigma$.

Note that $A = U \Sigma V^T \implies AV = U \Sigma$. Column by column, we see that $A v_i = \sigma_i u_i$, where $u_i$ and $v_i$ are the $i$th columns of $U$ and $V$, respectively, and $\sigma_i$ is the $i$th singular value of $A$.

So,
$$
\| A v_i \| = \sigma_i \| u_i \| = \sigma_i.
$$

Comment: But $sqrt(0.0002952607) \neq \sigma_4$?

Comment: @wcochran Yeah, there must be an error either in the logic in my answer or in the arithmetic in that example.

Comment: Fixed my arithmetic error. Thx.